# APR (Apache Portable Runtime) 1.2.2 RegEx?

Tags: c++, apache-portable-runtime

Does APR 1.2.2 have regex support?  Any documentation or tutorials on using it?

The documentation sucks.  Like really bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is straight from the book   [Writing Apache modules with Perl and C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/156592567X)

```
regex_t *ap_pregcomp (pool *p, const char *pattern, int cflags);
    void ap_pregfree (pool *p, regex_t *reg);
```

Apache supports regular expression matching using the system library's regular expression
routines regcomp(), regexec(), regerror(), and regfree(). If these functions are not available, then Apache uses its own package of regular expression routines. Documentation for the regular expression routines can be found in your system manual pages. If your system does not support these routines, the documentation for Apache's regular expression package can be found in the regex/ subdirectory of the Apache source tree.

Regular expression matching occurs in two phases. In the first phase, you call
regcomp() to compile a regular expression pattern string into a compiled form. In the second
phase, you pass the compiled pattern to regexec() to match the search pattern against a source string. In the course of performing its regular expression match, regexec() writes the offsets of each matched parenthesized subexpression into an array named pmatch[]. The significance of this array will become evident in the soon.

Apache provides wrapper routines around regcomp() and regfree() that
make working with regular expressions somewhat simpler. ap_pregcomp() works like
regcomp() to compile a regular expression string, except that it automatically allocates
memory for the compiled expression from the provided resource pool pointer. pattern
contains the string to compile, and cflags is a bit mask of flags that control the type of
regular expression to perform. The full list of flags can be found in the regcomp() manual
page.

In addition to allocating the regular expression, ap_pregcomp() automatically installs a
cleanup handler that calls regfree() to release the memory used by the compiled regular
expression when the transaction is finished.

Speaking of which, the cleanup handler installed by ap_pregcomp() is ap_pregfree(). It frees
the regular expression by calling regfree() and then removes itself from the cleanup handler
list to ensure that it won't be called twice. You may call ap_pregfree() yourself if, for some unlikely reason, you need to free up the memory used by the regular expression before the cleanup would have been performed normally.

```
char *ap_pregsub (pool *p, const char *input, const char *source, size_t nmatch,
regmatch_t pmatch[ ])
```

After performing a regular expression match with regexec(), you may use ap_pregsub() to
perform a series of string substitutions based on subexpressions that were matched during the operation. This function uses the pmatch[] array, which regexec() populates with the start and end positions of all the parenthesized subexpressions matched by the regular expression. You provide ap_pregsub() with p, a resource pool pointer, input, a character string describing the substitutions to perform, source, the source string used for the regular expression match, nmatch, the size of the pmatch array, and pmatch itself.
input is any arbitrary string containing the expressions $1 through $9. ap_pregsub() replaces these expressions with the corresponding matched subexpressions from the source string. $0 is also available for your use: it corresponds to the entire matched string.
The return value will be a newly allocated string formed from the substituted input string.

The following example shows ap_pregsub() being used to replace the .htm and .HTM
filename extensions with .html. We begin by calling ap_pregcomp() to compile the desired
regular expression and return the compiled pattern in memory allocated from the resource
pool. We specify flags that cause the match to be case-insensitive and to use the modern
regular expression syntax. We proceed to initialize the pmatch[] array to hold two regmatch_t elements. Two elements are needed: the first which corresponds to $0 and the
second for the single parenthesized subexpression in the pattern. Next we call regexec() with the compiled pattern, the requested filename, the pmatch[] array, and its length. The last argument to regexec(), which is used for passing various additional option flags, is set to zero. If regexec() returns zero, we go on to call ap_pregsub() to interpolate the matched subexpression (the filename minus its extension) into the string $1.html, effectively replacing the extension.

```
ap_regmatch_t pmatch[2];
ap_regex_t *cpat = ap_pregcomp(r->pool, "(.+)\\.htm$",
    AP_REG_EXTENDED|AP_REG_ICASE);
if (ap_regexec(cpat, r->filename, cpat->re_nsub+1, pmatch, 0) == 0)
{
  r->filename = ap_pregsub(r->pool, "$1.html",
      r->filename, cpat->re_nsub+1,
      pmatch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the documentation is terrible.

Looking here:

http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr-util/1.2/files.html

I'd venture a guess that no, there's no regex in 1.2.2.